# Is the login screen an entity or boundary class?

Tags: uml

I'm developing a student response system and the facilitator has to login. On analysis stage I have identified classes including login class. The problem is if I model login screen as entity class or boundary class.

Answer (score 4):

The terms 'boundary class' and 'entity class' are not defined by UML, but there are several methods, like RUP, which define those terms.

A screen is always a boundary class.